# archiving the table : searching for the best way

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, logging

there is a table which has 80.000 rows.
Everyday I will clone this table to another log table giving a name like 20101129_TABLE
, and every day the prefix will be changed according to date..

As you calculate, the data will be 2400 000 rows every month..

Advices please for saving space, and getting fast service and other advantages and disadvantages!! how should i think to create the best archive or log..

it is a table has the accounts info. branch code balance etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite tricky to answer your question since you are a bit vague on some important facts:

- How often do you need the archived tables?
- How free are you in your design-choices?

If you don't need the archived data often and you are free in your desgin I'd copy the data into an archive database. That will give you the option of storing the database on a separate disk (cost-efficiency) and you can have a separate backup-schedule on that database as well.

You could also store all the data in one table with just an additional column like `ArchiveDate datetime`. But I think this depends really on how you plan on accessing the data later.

Comment: No, that's a terrible suggestion! After few months, database would be unusable, digging through millions archive records just to get the current ones is bad design (too many index tree levels)

Comment: (Can't edit comments? Weird.) Without table partitioning performance would be unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **TABLE PARTITIONING** ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28SQL.90%29.aspx)) - it is designed for exactly this kind of scenarios. Not only you can spread data across partitions (and map partitions to different disks), you can keep all data in the same table and let MSSQL do all the hard work in the background (what partition to use based on select criteria, etc.).